Will a perfectly plastic body be able to store potential energy in it?
if we take a perfectly plastic body and then apply a deforming force $\ F_{def}$ on it which increases its length by $\Delta l$ .
the potential energy stored in a body is derived as
$\ U$ $= \ F_{avg}* \Delta l$
now the average deforming force is $\frac{F_{def}}{2}$
so $\ U$ $= \frac{F_{def}*\Delta l}{2}$
which means a perfectly plastic body should be able to store energy in the form of potential energy, if this is not true the i have another question: is there any way a perfectly plastic body will be able to store any type of energy in it?

The short answer is NO.  Because the force in your example is dissipative - the work performed has turned to heat energy, not potential energy.  It would be analogous to calculating the energy stored in a "dashpot."  To store mechanical potential energy, you would need a spring-like consistency with a restoring force -- this is a property of elastic bodies, not plastic ones.

how and why does it get converted to heat energy? and does that mean the temperature of plastic body would increase?

"How and why" are potentially deep questions that stretch the limits of my knowledge.  If you apply a surface traction to an element of perfectly elastic material, it deforms in a way consistent with its material properties and the applied loads.  If you remove the loads, the element returns to its original shape.  The source of this internal elasticity comes from the rigidity of the intermolecular structure deep inside the element.    A perfectly plastic material is more like a soup of molecules with no structure or rigidity.  Resistance to force is generated by friction of mlecules sliding.

Note that there is no such thing as a truly perfectly plastic material.  Maybe something like silly putty would be the closest example.  But to answer your second question, yes - the temperature of the plastic body would increase slightly with deformation.

got it, thanks.

As @MarianoG said, the body does not store potential energy. But it does get hotter. It stores energy as heat for a while. You can use the heat to get back some of the energy. For example, put the plastic object in contact with a gas filled cylinder and piston. The gas will expand and force the piston out.

Even a perfectly plastic material—of any phase—can generally store strain energy if it’s pressurized. Plasticity is related to so-called deviatoric stress, whereas pressurization is related to so-called dilatational or hydrostatic stress. Deviatoric loading tends to change the shape of an object; dilational loading tends to change its size.
However, there’s one more qualifier for strain energy storage: There must be some capacity for repulsion between the material’s constituent particles. The ideal gas, for example, lacks this capacity; pressurizing it at constant temperature doesn’t add internal energy but rather sinks entropy. It adds free energy.
An example of a perfectly plastic material that can store strain energy via compression but not via the incremental uniaxial loading that you describe is the ideal liquid. (Uniaxial loading simply causes it to rearrange without changing the intermolecular spacing.) Ductile solids just past their yield point exhibit approximately the same behavior.

Yes, a plastic body can store energy, if there are field forces
available.   One can mold a bit of clay into a tower.  Until the
tower pressure starts to deform the base, that stores a quantity
of gravitational potential energy in the object.   Similarly, a
plastic material can act to store magnetic or electric field
energy.
The difference between 'plastic' and 'fluid' is important for this
result, because a plastic material flow is negligible when forces
are small, while a fluid (liquid or gas) has no resistance to
applied force.   A sandpile is not exactly plastic, but might
also store energy.
